# Transloadit task never finishes

Tags: video, amazon-s3, transloadit

I'm working on a mobile app that stores images on S3, merges them into a video and pushes them to YouTube. I'm currently looking into moving the process to Transloadit as it would solve a lot of issues I'm having with it, but I can't seem to get it working properly.

The flow I plan is:

1. Fetch images from S3 bucket
2. Merge them into a video
3. Push video to YouTube

I've put together the following template for testing purposes:

```
{
  "steps": {
    "get_images": {
      "robot": "/s3/import",
      "key": "****",
      "secret": "****",
      "bucket": "image-test",
      "bucket-region": "eu-west-1",
      "path": [
        "uploaded_files/a9f80e0c-48a7-4411-bab6-c218efccec6e.jpg",
        "uploaded_files/e056a30b-03fb-4e7f-8e91-edf8a66494c5.jpg",
        "uploaded_files/bce0be54-0fd9-4367-ae87-b670214a4830.jpg",
        "uploaded_files/652dbaf0-7b4d-4dbc-9b51-a07e79d116a9.jpg"
      ]
    },
    "create_video": {
      "robot": "/video/merge",
      "preset": "flash",
      "width": 854,
      "height": 480,
      "resize_strategy": "fit",
      "framerate": "1/5",
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "get_images",
            "as": "image"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "youtube_upload": {
      "robot": "/youtube/store",
      "use": "create_video",
      "username": "Youtube User",
      "password": "****",
      "visibility": "unlisted",
      "category": "Film & Animation",
      "keywords": "blah",
      "title": "Test",
      "description": "Test"
    }
  }
}
```

The task never finishes execution. By deleting the steps, I've been able to establish that the first step runs and picks up the correct files, but the second step is never completed, suggesting that's where the problem lies. I've also observed that [the demo](https://transloadit.com/demos/video-encoding/generate-a-video-from-image-sequence) for generating a video doesn't appear to work either, which is a tad worrying.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to resolve this issue in the end by adding `"ffmpeg_stack": "v2.2.3",` to the `create_video` step.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figure this out! Just as a tip for the future, you might want to post this to our support directly to get an answer sooner.

We do keep an eye on SO, but not as often as on support system of course. :)

Kind regards,
Tim

Co-Founder Transloadit